# $e^{At}$ where $A$ is a $2 \times2$ or $3\times3$ matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to compute $e^A$ where $A$ is a  $2 \times2$ or $3\times3$  matrix.

Arnold's ODE book has a sample question which asks for $e^{At}$.
How does $t$ change the calculation? Should it be multiplied by the members of $A$, like a constant?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really change anything. Instead of
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
,
$$
you just use
$$
At=\begin{pmatrix} at & bt \\ ct & dt \end{pmatrix}
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the Jordan form $J$ of the matrix: in a Jordan basis, with change of basis matrix $P$, you have
$$P^{-1}AP=J=D+N, \quad \text{where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent.}$$
so $\;\mathrm e^{Jt}=\mathrm e^{(D+N)t}=\mathrm e^{Dt}\mathrm e^{Nt}$.  Now

- the exponential of a diagonal matrix $D(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)$ is just the diagonal matrix
  $$D\bigl(\mathrm e^{\lambda_1},\mathrm e^{\lambda_2},\dots,\mathrm e^{\lambda_n}\bigr).$$
- the exponential of a nilpotent matrix, with index of nilpotence $r$, is computed with the series expansion (which is a finite series in this case):
  $$\mathrm e^{Nt}=\Bigl(I+N+\tfrac12 N^2+\dots+\tfrac1{(r-1)!}N^{r-1}\Bigr)t.$$
  Once you have $\;\mathrm e^{Jt}$, you get back $\mathrm e^{At}$ in the standard basis with the reverse formula:
  $$\mathrm e^{At}=P\mathrm e^{Jt}P^{-1}.$$

Comment: Do $D$ and $N$ commute?

Answer (score 0):

I assume $t$ is a scalar. Then by definition
$$\exp(M)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}M^n$$
for any matrix $M$. Since you already know how to compute this, you can simply substitute $B=At$ and compute $\exp(B)$. Nothing changes at all. You cannot, however, do something like $\exp(At)=t\exp(A)$.